# Dumping twitter data, trying to process the csv file, program runs, but does no processing

Tags: python, csv, twitter

So to start I am new to python. I am dumping data from twitter straight to a csv file. I then wish to read that csv file using a program, and delete any cell containing information I do not declare. (when scraping data you receive a lot of information that is not usable or relevant). The code is not complete, but the core syntax is below, and I was going to run a test to see if it would do what I requested of it. It runs the program, and finishes, but never does anything to the existing csvfile I am having it open, read, and delete cells from.

My question is, does anyone see anything wrong with the code? other than it being unfinished and could be condensed. I am still only a week new to python, and trying to learn as i go. Any feedback would be appreciated.

```
import csv

f = open('csvdata.csv', 'r+', newline= '')
reader = csv.DictReader(f, fieldnames=None , dialect='excel')
x = 0
y = 0


for row in reader:



    try:
        cell = row[y][x]

        if 'created_at' in cell:
            x = x+1


        elif 'id:' in cell:
            x = x+1


        elif 'text:' in cell:
            x = x+1


 ####elif box starts with '':
    ####x = x+1
    ####continue

        elif 'source:' in cell:
            x = x+1


        elif 'user:{' in cell:
            x = x+1


        elif 'name:' in cell:
            x = x+1


        elif 'screen_name:' in cell:
            x = x+1


        elif 'location:' in cell:
            x = x+1


        elif 'url:' in cell:
            x = x+1


        elif 'description' in cell:
            x = x+1


        elif 'translator_type:' in cell:
            x = x+1


        elif 'protected' in cell:
            x = x+1


        elif 'verified' in cell:
            x = x+1


        elif 'followers' in cell:
            x = x+1


        elif 'friends' in cell:
            x = x+1


        elif 'listed' in cell:
            x = x+1


        elif 'favourites' in cell:
            x = x+1


        elif 'statuses' in cell:
            x = x+1


        elif 'time' in cell:
            x = x+1


        elif 'lang:' in cell:
            x = x+1


        elif 'is_translator' in cell:
            x = x+1


        elif 'default_profile' in cell:
            x = x+1


        elif 'notification' in cell:
            x = x+1


        elif 'geo:' in cell:
            x = x+1


        elif 'coordinates:' in cell:
            x = x+1


        elif 'place:' in cell:
            x = x+1


        elif 'contributors:' in cell:
            x = x+1


        elif 'quoted_status' in cell:
            x = x+1


        elif 'retweeted_status' in cell:
            x = x+1


        else:
            del_cell
            x = x+1



    except:
        y = y+1
```

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, you're using `DictWriter` instead of `DictReader`. Then as a debugging step, try to print out the rows as they are read just to make sure that you are actually reading the correct data.

Comment: That error implies that you are still using `DictWriter`. Can you please paste the actual error message when you use `DictReader`?